# Вместо главной страницы открывается "сайт на разработке"

Tags: netcat, php, cms

Здравствуйте.

Есть сайт на NetCat. При вводе доменного имени открывается страница "реконструкция", а "главная" только если дописать /index.

В сайте есть Настройки. Там есть Титульная страница. Выбираю нужную. Но кнопка "сохранить изменения" не срабатывает.

Как сделать, чтоб кнопка срабатывала? Никто не сталкивался с такой проблемой?

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Не может ли быть проблема в файле index.php

```
<?php

$NETCAT_FOLDER=join(strstr(__FILE__,"/")? "/" : "\\",array_slice(preg_split("/[\/\\\]+/",__FILE__),0,-1)).(strstr(__FILE__,"/")? "/" : "\\");
include_once($NETCAT_FOLDER."vars.inc.php");
require($INCLUDE_FOLDER."e404.php");

?>
```

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема вряд ли в index.php.

Есть варианты:

1. Разобраться с настройками netcat (с вероятностью 80% там будет нужная настройка);
2. Можно попробовать решить "в лоб", прописав в index.php строку: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/index';

Comment: была проблема в неправильном обновлении системы netcat её работниками,  вдруг кто-то тоже столкнется)